# How to not pass the value by function when using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There is an api as below.
try catch is omitted here.

```
exports.test = async(req,res) => {
    const {clientId} = req.body;

  // There is a function that makes an object to use repeatedly.
  function errorReason(arg1) {
    const errorLogs = new ErrorLogs({
      clientId,
      reason: arg1,
    });
    return errorLogs;
  }

  errorReason("server error").save();
```

And this is the type of clientId.

```
clientId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
```

When I can pass obejctId or empty String for clientId as request.body.
But when I send empty string, it occurs an error.

> validation failed: clientId: Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"\"
>   at path \"clientId\"

How can I make correct function of errorReason? I don't want to save "null" or "empty string" for clientId, even though clientId is empty string. 
I hope there isn't clientId for 'new ErrorLogs', when clientId is empty string.

```
  function errorReason(arg1) {
    const errorLogs = new ErrorLogs({
      reason: arg1,
    });
    return errorLogs;
  }
```

Thank you so much for reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by making the `required` field in your schema consume a function. This function decides whether the field is required depending on the type. This will allow you to save an empty string.
If you want to save an empty string:

**to save an empty string:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const errorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    clientId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: function(){
            return typeof this.clientId === 'string' ? false : true
        },
    }
});


const Errors = mongoose.model('errors', errorSchema)
```

**Update:** Seems I misunderstood your intention. If you just want to not set the field `clientId` in the document, pass `undefined` to the Schema when you have an empty string. Mongoose will not save the field (unless you have it required, in which case mongoose will throw an error)

**exclude empty string field from saved document:**

```
function errorReason(arg1) {
  const errorLogs = new ErrorLogs({
    clientId: clientId || undefined, // handles '', undefined, null, NaN etc
    reason: arg1,
  });
  return errorLogs;
}

errorReason("server error").save();
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want to save if it is empty string.

Comment: @DDDD I've updated the answer. Just do a check for `clientId` is not an empty string before executing your code no? Or are you trying to say you don't want to save the field `clientId` when its an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

You should use code like bellow.

```
exports.test = async(req,res) => {
const {clientId} = req.body;

// There is a function that makes an object to use repeatedly.
function errorReason(arg1) {
const errorLogs = new ErrorLogs({
    clientId : clientId, // add here clientId for asign clientId to field
    reason: arg1,
});
return errorLogs;
}

if(!!clientId){ //Here !! means not equal to blank,null,undefine and 0
    errorReason("server error").save();
}
```